# Office 2016 for Mac Replace Text only works for first couple of instances?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I am new to VBA for Mac an so far not impressed, cannot even create a userform which is how I would normally have accomplished this task.

I want to have message boxes come up and ask me for information that will then populate multiple instances via search and replace.

For example the first part is to ask for the document author and once the msgbox has the answer it will then replace the string  in the document.

I have tried many different variations but in every case after the first two msgbox sections I get an error:

```
Sub auto_open()
 
Dim Author As String
Dim Title As String
Dim Longname As String
Dim Shortname As String
Dim Reference As String
Dim Createdate As String
Dim myStoryRange As Range


Author = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter your name here please.", _
      Title:="Document Author", Default:="Your Name here")

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = "<Document Author>"
    .Replacement.Text = Author
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    End With

Title = InputBox(Prompt:="Proposal, Maintenance Agreement etc?", _
      Title:="Document Title", Default:="Proposal")

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = "<Document Title>"
    .Replacement.Text = Title
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    End With


Longname = InputBox(Prompt:="Client's full legal name as per their ABN or ACN", _
      Title:="Client's Full Name", Default:="      Pty Ltd")

    With ActiveDocument.Content
    .Find.Text = "<Long Customer Name>"
    .Replacement.Text = Longname
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    End With


Shortname = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the usual name by which the client is known.", _
      Title:="Client's short name or abbreviation", Default:="  ")

    With ActiveDocument.Content
    .Find.Text = "<Short Customer Name>"
    .Replacement.Text = Shortname
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    End With


Reference = InputBox(Prompt:="Use the number generated by Sales Force", _
      Title:="Reference/Proposal number", Default:="  ")

    With ActiveDocument.Content
    .Find.Text = "<Reference Number>"
    .Replacement.Text = Reference
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    End With


Createdate = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter todays date or the date you will submit this proposal", _
      Title:="Date document created", Default:=Now())

    With ActiveDocument.Content
    .Find.Text = "<Date Created>"
    .Replacement.Text = Createdate
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    End With
     
End Sub
```

As you can see here the section for Author and Title work fine but the exact same code for `LongName` and onwards do not??

(Sorry tried to show picture but not allowed yet)

End result is once the code gets to `LongName` it errors with:

> Compile error:
>
> Method or data member not found
> (ThisDocument 34:8)

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the first two cases, you have

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
```

but in the subsequent cases you have

```
With ActiveDocument.Content
```

I would expect the first line after the With to work because you have correctly used ".Find.Text", but I would not expect the ".Replacement.Text = ..." line to work because it would need to be ".Find.Replacement.Text = ..."

Comment: Thankyou thankyou, how could I miss something so obvious? This is the result of a cut and paste error where the .find ended up on the next line. It all works perfectly now. Thankyou again bibadia